# How to enable flags with automake specific to GCC

Tags: gcc, automake

I'm new to automake, but found my way through the docs and have everything building as I like.  However, I currently have CFLAGS="-Wall -Werror" turned on.  While this is great for gcc, I'm assuming that someone is going to build my code with a non-gcc compiler.  What's the correct way to detect whether GCC is being used and to only set those flags for GCC?

**Edit**

The solution looks like this:

1. Download http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_check_compile_flag.html and place the macro in your project's ./m4/ directory.
2. Add the following lines to your configure.ac:

   ```
   AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-Wall], [CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -Wall"], [], [])
   AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([-Werror], [CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -Werror"], [], [])
   ```

**Edit 2**

This macro might also be more useful than -Wall since it does the same for multiple compilers: http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_cflags_warn_all.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check whether each flag is supported using an Autoconf macro such as [`AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_check_compile_flag.html).